# Populating Input Field With CFC JSON Results

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

I have a form setup where I am selecting a name from the list, calling a CFC and running a query against that name. I then return a dollar amount from that query.

I am then trying to take that dollar amount and change the value of an `<input>` element.

I can successfully run my CFC and return the correct value, but my JQUERY doesn't change the value of my input field. It skips my success: method and goes right to my error: method.

Here is my form code:

```
<cfselect class="required" queryPosition="below" query="get_ticket" display="company_name" name="customer_checkout" id="customer_checkout" tabindex="0" onchange="PopulateGrandTotal();" ><option>---Make A Selection---</option></cfselect>

<div id="grant_totalDIV" >
        <input type="number" name="grand_total_due"   id="grand_total_due"> 
</div>
```

Here is my CFC:

```
<cffunction name="getTotal" access="remote" returntype="any">
<cfargument name="customer_checkout" type="any" required="true">

<!--- localize function variables --->
<cfset var dataDetail = "">

<cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#" >
select grand_total
from service_ticket
where company_name = '#customer_checkout#'
</cfquery> 


<cfoutput query="dataDetail">

    <cfreturn dataDetail.grand_total>
</cfoutput>
</cffunction></cfcomponent>
```

Here is JQuery:

```
<script>
function PopulateGrandTotal(){
    // Populate the customer alert DIV based on the customer selection
    console.log( $("#customer_checkout>option:selected").attr("Value") );

    $.ajax({
        url:'cfcs/grand_totalDIV.cfc?method=getTotal&returnformat=json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { customer_checkout: $("#customer_checkout>option:selected").attr("Value") },

        success: function(response) {
            console.log('Successfully ran JSON, now changing input value');
            $("#grand_total_due").val( response );

            console.log('Input value cahnged');

            },
        error: function(response){ 

                console.log('Error');

                }
      });
}
</script>
```

My JSON Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>
<body>

</body>
274.00
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are simply returning text so don't use `dataType: 'json',` since that's not what is being sent.

You can just remove that option from the ajax configuration

Otherwise you would need to json serialize a struct and access the correct property within your success handler

Comment: OK, I've commented out that part of the code, and now it runs the success: method as I can see it logging the messages that I've coded in there. But it is not changing the value of my input field with the response. Is that part of my code correct?

Comment: try logging the response to console

Comment: UPDATE: I changed the type for the input field from number to text, now it is changing my value to this: </head><body></body>274.00

Comment: ooooo looks like you have some html in that CFC also

Comment: ok, I've updated my original question with the JSON response.

Comment: somehow you are returning an html page with your `<cfoutput>` being added after `<body>`. Should only see the text value returned , nothing else

Comment: I can't seem to determine why my response would be returning HTML code. If I run the CFC separately, in a browser windows, it just shows the value I am returning, no HTML code. Should this be asked in a separate question?

Comment: This question resolved my HTML code in my JSON response issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707408/json-response-from-my-cfc-is-retunring-html-code/35707661#35707661

Comment: Ahhh makes sense. I haven't done much coldfusion for quite a while

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for comments)

You should also align the return types, so both sides are in agreement on what type data is being returned and in what format. If you prefer to return plain text, rather than JSON:

- Set the CFFunction to use the appropriate return type ie `returntype="numeric"` or `returntype="string"`
- Then tell CF which format it should use by supplying the `returnformat` parameter, and use `dataType` to tell jQuery what type of data it should expect to receive. As mentioned in the comments, the default is do an [intelligent guess: (xml, json, script, or html)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). However, supplying it does not hurt anything, and specifying it explicitly helps avoids inadvertent mix ups like the initial json/text issue IMO.

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url:'cfcs/grand_totalDIV.cfc?method=getTotal&returnformat=plain',
      dataType: 'text',
      ...
  });
  ```

Also, nothing to do with your error, but a few tips:

- Since the function is not actually displaying anything, there is no need for a `<cfoutput query="...">`. Just return the single value: `<cfreturn dataDetail.grand_total>`
- If the function requires a specific type of value for the `customer_checkout` (ie string, number, etcetera), specify it in argument signature, rather than using `type="any"`.
- Always use `cfqueryparam` to boost performance and protect against SQL injection
- Do not forget to scope all variables, ie `arguments.customer_checkout` instead of `customer_checkout`

Comment: FYI `plain` isn't a valid datatype...  "text" ..or "html" would be but intelligent guess built in will default to text/html anyway

Comment: @charlietfl - Oops, thanks. That was a copy + paste error.  I will update it.  Sure, it *can* guess, but my suggestion to align the types was for mostly to emphasize where the "format" fits into the picture and that there's a relationship between the two sides (Honestly, it did not seem like it was entirely clear to the asker).