# JSON response from my CFC is retunring HTML code

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

I have a strange issue here. I am making a call to a CFC using jquery and returning a string. I am then trying to populate a form field with that string. For some reason, my response is including HTML code along with the query results.

Here is how the JSON response looks in the console:

```
> Gary Turner check_out.cfm:146 Successfully ran JSON, now changing
> input value check_out.cfm:149 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML
> 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
> 
> </head> <body>
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> </body>
> 274.00
```

Here is my JQUERY:

```
 <!---Populate Grand Total  --->   
  <script>
  function PopulateGrandTotal(){
    // Populate the customer alert DIV based on the customer selection
    console.log( $("#customer_checkout>option:selected").attr("Value") );

    $.ajax({
        url:'cfcs/grand_totalDIV.cfc?method=getTotal&returnformat=json',
        //dataType: 'text',
        data: { customer_checkout:        $("#customer_checkout>option:selected").attr("Value") },

        success: function(response) {
            console.log('Successfully ran JSON, now changing input   value');
            $("#grand_total_due").val( response );

            console.log(response);

            },
        error: function(response){ 

                console.log('Error');

                }
      });
 }
 </script>
```

Here is my CFC:

```
    <cffunction name="getTotal" access="remote" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="customer_checkout" type="any" required="true">

    <!--- localize function variables --->
    <cfset var dataDetail = "">

    <cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#" >
    select grand_total
    from service_ticket
    where company_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.customer_checkout#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery> 

    <cfoutput query="dataDetail">
        <cfreturn dataDetail.grand_total>
    </cfoutput>
</cffunction></cfcomponent>
```

Here is my Form:

```
<cfform id="form" name="form" method="post" action="signature_popup.cfm" >



      <br><br>
        <div align="center"><cfselect class="required" queryPosition="below" query="get_ticket" display="company_name" name="customer_checkout" id="customer_checkout" tabindex="0" onchange="PopulateGrandTotal();" ><option>---Make A Selection---</option></cfselect>
      <br><br>
        <div id="grant_totalDIV" >
            <h2><label for="grand_total_due">Total Amount Due:</label><input type="text" name="grand_total_due" id="grand_total_due">   </h2>
        </div>
      <br>
```

Comment: What happens when you declare `returnFormat="json"` in your CFC method?

Comment: I recieve the same html in my response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at your Application.cfc file - or Application.cfm - it is probably setting up header/footer values. Look for "onrequestend()" and "Onrequest()" or "onrequeststart()" - that might clue you in.

You might also have a custom tag type approach in there -- something that wraps every request.

Your *returnType will need to be set to json* - otherwise you just get "274.00" with no json wrappers.

To fix the HTML you have check for a CFC and not run the function in question. Alternately you can use a separate Application.cfc in the folder of your CFCs that excludes those functions altogether. Such a separate Application.cfc is not in play when you access your CFC's directly from code (as in createobject()) - but comes in to play when they are the base template for a request as in your example.

Remember that you can test right from the browser using method=getTotal& etc. - no need to troubleshoot this in the console until you get the results correct in the browser.

Comment: Brian - what was it?

Comment: Ah.... You were totally right. My application.cfm was incorrect in the folder that was housing my CFC file. Thanks!! All good now.

Comment: awesome! glad I could be of help. :)